# Spring web app in tomcat: failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, junit, classnotfoundexception

In a web application running in tomcat, I see these dumps in catalina.out, it complains about org.inuit.Test class not found, and the error repeat itself hundreds of times. While the error is not fatal as indicated, it becomes an nuisance.

Can someone tell me how this can be fixed?

```
2021-09-15 04:10:42,382 [main] WARN  org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor:-1 - Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Test
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1483) ~[catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329) ~[catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167) ~[spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) [spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.buildDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:404) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.readPersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:382) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:341) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:326) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:235) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4244) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4743) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap-6.0.24.jar:na]
```

Comment: Look for `@Test` annotations in your code, there should be none (the test code should not be compiled into the WAR file).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, awesome! Per your advice, I removed the *-test.jar under WEB-INF/lib and the reported errors were gone. Thank you very much!